# Add Horizontal Scroll bar to table in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, bootstrap-4

I want to have an Horizontal scroll bar to my table.

Html code:

As you can see i have already used bootstrap but still it is not working. in other modules it is working fine.
The tbody data is added after an ajax is called.

I have also tried with :

```
overflow-x: auto
white-space: nowrap
```

The data is not showing properly to the right side: it is going outside the screen size i have to zoom it out to see the whole table.

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="new-modal">
  <div class="tble-grid-wrapper">
    <div class="table-responsive pl-3 pr-3">
      <table id="selectedDevices" class="table table-sm table-striped" class="display">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>HEADER 1</th>
            <th>HEADER 2</th>
            <th>HEADER 3</th>
            <th>HEADER 4</th>
            <th>HEADER 5</th>
            <th>HEADER 6</th>
            <th>HEADER 7</th>
            <th>HEADER 8</th>
            <th>HEADER 9</th>
            <th>HEADER 10</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: enclose your table in a div. Constrain this div to 100% width. Add `overflow-x:auto` to this div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="new-modal" style="width:100%;overflow-x:scroll;">
  <div class="tble-grid-wrapper">
    <div class="table-responsive pl-3 pr-3">
      <table id="selectedDevices" class="table table-sm table-striped" class="display">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>HEADER 1</th>
            <th>HEADER 2</th>
            <th>HEADER 3</th>
            <th>HEADER 4</th>
            <th>HEADER 5</th>
            <th>HEADER 6</th>
            <th>HEADER 7</th>
            <th>HEADER 8</th>
            <th>HEADER 9</th>
            <th>HEADER 10</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

what you are looking for is `width: 100%; overflow-x: scroll`

Comment: `overflow-y` is vertical.

Comment: @shtse8 sorry still not working going outside the screen size

Comment: @AmitRathod you need to set the width before using `overflow:scroll`, check snippet

Comment: @shtse8 even if i add width = 100% it is still going outside the screen size to the right.

Comment: @AmitRathod You need to set the 100% width at the top of the `div`, and ensure every nested `div` got the 100% width.

Comment: Use `width: 100vw` then, this is bulletproof. 100% means "100% of the parent", but if the parent is already larger than the screen, it won't work. 100vw means "100% of the Viewport's Width" and does not depend on anything else.

Comment: @JeremyThille I cannot as my reputation points are not >15 but your answer is correct. thanks for the help

Comment: No worries that's fine. You're welcome :)

Answer (score 5):

1. Enclose your table in a div (which is already done, in your case)
2. Constrain this div with `width:100vw`. This is bulletproof. `width:100%` means "100% of the parent's width", but if the parent is already larger than the screen, it won't work. `width:100vw` means "100% of the Viewport's Width" and does not depend on anything else.
3. Add `overflow-x: auto` to allow horizontal scrollbar. Job done

Demo below

```css
#new-modal {
    width : 100vw;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="new-modal">
  <div class="tble-grid-wrapper">
    <div class="table-responsive pl-3 pr-3">
      <table id="selectedDevices" class="table table-sm table-striped" class="display">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>HEADER 1</th>
            <th>HEADER 2</th>
            <th>HEADER 3</th>
            <th>HEADER 4</th>
            <th>HEADER 5</th>
            <th>HEADER 6</th>
            <th>HEADER 7</th>
            <th>HEADER 8</th>
            <th>HEADER 9</th>
            <th>HEADER 10</th>
            <th>HEADER 11</th>
            <th>HEADER 12</th>
            <th>HEADER 13</th>
            <th>HEADER 14</th>
            <th>HEADER 15</th>
            <th>HEADER 16</th>
            <th>HEADER 17</th>
            <th>HEADER 18</th>
            <th>HEADER 19</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```